# How to specify a sibling field type given an enum value?

Tags: typescript

I'm sort of new to typescript so I'm trying to figure out how to best do this:

I have a case where for each enum value in a list, there is a specific set of properties to be assigned.

```
type Type = "type-1" | "type-2";

interface TypeOneProps {
    value: string;
};

interface TypeTwoProps {
    count: number;
};

...

interface ValueWrapper {
    type: Type;
    properties: TypeOneProps | TypeTwoProps;
}
```

I would like for type of "type-1" to matched with TypeOneProps, etc.

I haven't been able to figure it out - any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's a good idea to combine the final interfaces instead of the `Type` type:

```
interface TypeOne {
    value: "type-1";
    properties: TypeOneProps;
};

interface TypeTwo {
    value: "type-2";
    properties: TypeTwoProps;
};
```

And then your final interface can be:

```
type ValueWrapper = TypeOne | TypeTwo;
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add a third item to ValueWrapper? Does this extend well?